# Expose Heroku Postgres database to an external app

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have an Heroku Postgres database that I want to share with certain external systems.

The docs says ([link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku)):

> Heroku Postgres databases are designed to be used with a Heroku app.
>   However, except for private and shield tier databases, they are
>   accessible from anywhere and may be used from any application using
>   standard Postgres clients. For private databases, outside access can
>   be enabled using trusted IP ranges.

Current external systems can't use Postgres JDBC driver for some security constraints. How can I give them access to Postgres database it in a secure way?

Comment: if they can't use JDBC how would they connect to the database?

Comment: I'm looking for alternatives (heroku app? api?)

Comment: I mean... if you want to connect directly to the database you're going to need PostgreSQL drivers. If you're going to go through another application or build an API you're not connecting to the database. At that point I'm not sure that your question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

All Heroku Postgres databases are [public](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku), with the exception of their `private` and `shield` tier databases which have additional network restrictions.

As long as you use a Postgres appropriate driver and require [ssl on connections](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku#ssl) there is nothing preventing your external client from connecting to a Heroku Postgres instance.

One additional thing to consider is that fact that your Heroku Postgres instance may be moved to a new host during maintenance operations. You can stay abreast of any changes by polling the [platform api.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#add-on-config)